# Pyspark not working and throwing java exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I started working with pyspark, i have installed it and running on jupyter-notebook, here is the problem i am facing about gateway process failing. I have even tried setting $JAVA_HOME but it didn't work. I want to know what is the reason behind and how to fix it.

Error in jupyter-notebook

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

.bashrc file

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.6

export SPARK_HOME='/home/junaid/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7'
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'

export HADOOP_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.7.3
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HOME/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.7.3
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.7.3
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.7.3
export YARN_HOME=$HOME/hadoop-2.7.3
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/hadoop-2.7.3/bin

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
```

notebook-code

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local")
```

I have even tried with

```
sc = SparkContext("local", "count app")
```

but didn't work.